# How to Capture Specific React Warnings in Sentry with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, sentry

I am working on a Next.js application and using Sentry for error tracking. I've successfully configured Sentry to capture errors in my `try/catch` blocks, but I'm facing challenges in capturing specific errors and warnings at a global level, within my `sentry.client.config.ts` file. An example warning that I want to capture is:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by CandidateTable. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
```

**sentry.client.config.ts**

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";

const dsn = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN;

Sentry.init({
  dsn,
  tracesSampleRate: 1,
  debug: false,
  replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
  replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
  integrations: [
    new Sentry.Replay({
      maskAllText: true,
      blockAllMedia: true,
    }),
  ],
});

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // Attach error event listener
  window.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
    Sentry.captureException(event.error);
  });

  // Attach unhandledrejection event listener
  window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (event) => {
    Sentry.captureException(event.reason);
  });

  // Override console.error
  const originalConsoleError = console.error;
  console.error = (...args: any[]) => {
    Sentry.captureException(new Error(args.join(" ")));
    originalConsoleError.apply(console, args);
  };

  // Override console.warn
  const originalConsoleWarn = console.warn;
  console.warn = function (...args) {
    // Check if the warning message is related to React's hooks order
    if (typeof args[0] === "string" && args[0].includes("Rules of Hooks")) {
      Sentry.captureMessage(`React Hook Order Warning: ${args.join(" ")}`, "warning");
    }
    originalConsoleWarn.apply(console, args);
  };
}

export {};
```

I know the connection between my project works, as I can send their sample errors from the sample page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js will catch React errors internally and doesn't pass them to any global error handlers. You can set up a custom `_error` page though which the errors will be passed to.

Information about custom error pages: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error

How it would look like with Sentry instrumentation:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import type { ErrorProps } from "next/error";
import Error from "next/error";

const CustomErrorComponent: NextPage<ErrorProps> = (props) => {
  return <Error statusCode={props.statusCode} />;
};

CustomErrorComponent.getInitialProps = async (contextData) => {
  // In case this is running in a serverless function, await this in order to give Sentry
  // time to send the error before the lambda exits
  await Sentry.captureUnderscoreErrorException(contextData);

  // This will contain the status code of the response
  return Error.getInitialProps(contextData);
};

export default CustomErrorComponent;
```

(Docs for this can be found here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#report-react-component-render-errors)